# After upgrading fancybox to 2.1 the images get a default of 100px height

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

All images gets a 100px height, and auto width on top of screen - not centered (the images are higher than 100px). This happened when I upgraded to 2.1, latest version today. Is this a bug in the latest build?

The size seems to be correct when using the resize button - but still not centered vertically.

```
    $("a[href*='.jpeg'], a[href*='.jpg'], a[href*='.png'], a[href*='.gif']").attr("rel", "imagegroup").fancybox({
        prevEffect: 'elastic',
        nextEffect: 'elastic',
        helpers: {
            title: null,
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.8,
                css: {
                    'background-color': '#000'
                }
            },
            thumbs: { // remove if you do not want thumbnails at bottom
                width: 50,
                height: 50
            },
            buttons: {} // remove if you do not want buttons at top
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. You may have upgraded the js files but forgot to upgrade the css files.

Fancybox **js** file `v2.1.0` with fancybox **css** file `v2.0.6` (or lower) will produce images 100px height and aligned to the top of the window.

[SEE DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/imagesResizedTo100px_04sep12.html)

Comment: Yeah, it was my bad! I updated the CSS files to the wrong folder :/ Thank you very much, saved med some debugging time :)  We have bought the license, well worth it! Great product.