# How to resize Fancybox after the image changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have PHP code to generate a graph, it runs with AJAX, and then it would show up in hidden  and using id I show it in fancy box, it works but it takes time for PHP to run and fancy box at first shows loader, then an image is finnally made it would apear in fancybox but it's size stays the same 50px x 50px (or something). I tryed every solution on this link [How do you resize Fancybox at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994876/how-do-you-resize-fancybox-at-runtime)   none of it worked or I was donig something wrong(I'm just starting with whole JS). It shows whole image after the window is resized maybe I could simulate some kind of resizing with some function, I don't know...Thanks in advance!

Added code (I don't think it will help):

JS

```
function graph2() 
{

  var ajax = getRequest();
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
      if(ajax.readyState == 4)
      {
          document.getElementById('graph').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
      }

  }
  document.getElementById('graph').innerHTML = "<br/><img src=img/ajax-loader.gif><br/><br/>";
  ajax.open("GET", "graph_2.php?", true);
  ajax.send(null);
}
```

HTML

```
<a class="graph" rel="group" onclick='graph2(); return false;' id="menu_button" href="#graph">Skambučiai per diena</a>
<span id="graph" display="none"></span>
```

Fancybox

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".graph").fancybox(
    {
          helpers: 
          {
              title : 
              {
                  type : 'float'
              }
          },
          autoSize : true,

    });
```

Comment: that normally happens when the versions of fancybox js and css files don't mach ;) (for instance js is v2.1.5 and css is v2.0.6) ... check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12258702/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [After upgrading fancybox to 2.1 the images get a default of 100px height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258357/after-upgrading-fancybox-to-2-1-the-images-get-a-default-of-100px-height)

Comment: Well thats not the case, becouse I just downloaded it yesterday from official site. And I checked all versions they are the same - 2.1.5

Comment: can you share a link?

Comment: Of what ? Site I downloaded from ?

Comment: the site with the issue ... you are not posting any code or providing any element we can use to figure out what you might be doing wrong

Comment: The site is not published yet. But I'll update the code.

Comment: where is the fancybox code?

Comment: have you tried adding `type:"image"` to your API options? (the graph is an image, isn't it?)

Comment: Yes it is an image, but now it says that the content cannot be loaded.

Comment: what does the function `getRequest()` do?

Comment: `Added code (I don't think it will help):` ... you are so optimistic

Comment: It's for AJAX so that I could run php script without reloading page, it creates XMLHttpRequest object. (Atleast thats how I understand it.) So it's not related. Problem is that the image is created after the Fancybox is opened thats why it stays in default small size, I need to resize it or open it after a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your code does but if I pull the *image* directly into fancybox instead of populating a `span` tag (formatting `span` tags has its drawbacks by the way), the *image* is displayed correctly.

Since you are already using jQuery (with fancybox) this `ajax` code (without needing the `onclick` attribute) does the trick too :

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".fancybox").on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      url: "returnImage.php",
      success: function(data) {
        $.fancybox(data,{
          helpers: {
            title:  {
              type: 'float'
            }
          },
          autoSize: true
        });
      }
    }); // ajax
    return false;
  }); // on
}); // ready
```

with this html of course

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#test">get image via ajax in fancybox</a>
```

My php file (for demo purposes) only returns an image :

```
<?php 
echo "<img src=\"images/01.jpg\" alt=\"test\" />";
?>
```

See **[DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/getImageAjax.html)**

**EDIT** :

After further testing (in Chrome) the image remained in the smallest possible size (100px) once shown in fancybox.

The workaround is to wait a bit (around half a second) for the image to be fully loaded in the fancybox container and then to run the method `$.fancybox.update()` inside the `afterShow` callback like :

```
  afterShow: function(){
    var resize = setTimeout(function(){
      $.fancybox.update();
    },500);
  }
```

I updated the **[DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/getImageAjax.html)** with this patch.